# Icon for ‘backwards compatible’?

Tags: icon, symbolism

#### How can I represent *backwards compatibility* in an icon?

Our company makes building control systems and we are currently developing a whole new platform/range (hardware and software) which will eventually supersede our current platform.  This supersession process is expected to take at least 5 years due to the long lifecycle of the hardware so backwards compatibility is an important aspect of the sales process for the new platform.

I am building up the web content for the new platform and need an icon to indicate the backwards compatibility of the new platform.

Unfortunately, neither the old or new platforms have their own icon (e.g. PlayStation 2/3/4 icons) so I don't have existing visual elements I can use to, for example, point a double-ended arrow at.

While I would like to avoid text because it does not work at small scale, I have been unable to come up with anything image-only that works.

Here is what I have so far:

[image: first draft icon]

Answer (score 5):

So I did some more thinking on this and here is what I have come up with:

[image: backwards compatible icon]

This focuses on the old and new platforms 'working' together, rather than 'communicating'.

Comment: I wanted to ask if it's okay to use this icon on our eBay description page.
We are a business who sales car parts and we are using icons which have been purchased but for compatibility, we couldn't find anything. This one seems to be perfect for our use.
Please let me know because we won't be using it if it's copyright protected. Regards
Hamid Hosseini